# How many robes is Dumbledore wearing in this passage from Harry Potter?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-number

How many robes is Dumbledore wearing in this passage from Harry Potter?

> Nothing like this man had ever been seen on Privet Drive. He was tall, thin, and very old, judging by the silver of his hair and beard, which were both long enough to tuck into his belt. He was wearing long robes, a purple cloak that swept the ground, and high-heeled, buckled boots. His blue eyes were light, bright, and sparkling behind half-moon spectacles and his nose was very long and crooked, as though it had been broken at least twice. This man's name was Albus Dumbledore.

(From *Philosopher's Stone*/*Sorcerer's Stone*)

Does the word "robes," in plural, imply that he's actually wearing multiple robes?

Answer (score 7):

> Does the word "robes" imply that he's actually wearing multiple robes?

No, not necessarily. From *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/robe#:%7E:text=You%20can%20describe%20someone%20as%20wearing%20a%20robe%20or%20as%20wearing%20robes.&text=Pope%20John%20Paul%20II%20knelt,robes%20before%20the%20simple%20altar.&text=A%20robe%20is%20a%20piece,up%20or%20taken%20a%20bath.)*:

> COUNTABLE NOUN
> A robe is a loose piece of clothing that covers all of your body and reaches the ground. **You can describe someone as wearing a *robe* or as wearing *robes*.**
> [formal]
> *Pope John Paul II knelt in his white robes before the simple altar.*

To say that someone is wearing robes can be interpreted to be the same as saying that they are wearing *a* robe. (Though this does seem to be a more formal way to put it)

Rowling seems to prefer the plural version, as she consistently uses it.

From a logical standpoint, too, it makes sense: Even Dumbledore, for all his brilliance, would probably struggle to wear multiple robes at once.

Comment: Hi. I agree with everything in your answer except the last sentence. I don't know about wizards in Rowling's world, but historically it has been pretty common to wear several layers of robes, and in particular several layers of dresses for women. Robes in general let the breeze enter under your clothes, which can be pretty cold, so wearing several layers makes sense. I wouldn't be surprised if this was even the historical reason why "robes" can be plural.

Comment: @Stef - yeah, you're right. That was a bit poorly thought out.

Comment: Surely when one chooses 'He was wearing robes' as merely a variant (as Collins implies) of 'He was wearing a robe', 'robes' is plural-form noncount. You can't have 'He was wearing 1 robes', and 'He was/They were wearing 2/3/... robes' is the count usage. Compare 'He was wearing trousers'.

Answer (score 3):

No.  He cold be wearing one article of clothing, described as "robes".

I looked on the web.  The description for this picture is: "The New Muslim Arab Middle East Men's Robes"

[image: pic]

Comment: But "men's" also appears in the caption.